# How to create a DataFrame from a list that each column is created by a regex expression

Tags: python-3.x, regex, dataframe

I have a list as such:

```
lst = ['2021_01_21__11_10_54_1__13928_snapshot.jpg',
       '2021_01_21__12_27_44_1__13934_snapshot.jpg',
       '2021_01_21__11_11_08_2__13928_snapshot.jpg',
       '2021_01_21__12_27_56_2__13934_snapshot.jpg',
       '2021_01_21__11_11_19_3__13928_snapshot.jpg',
       '2021_01_21__12_28_08_3__13934_snapshot.jpg']
```

I want to create a DataFrame so that each column will be represented by:

```
def by_number(path):
    base_name = os.path.basename(path)
    return re.findall('[\_]{2}(\d{5})',lst)
```

And the rows will be represented by:

```
def by_index(path):
    base_name = os.path.basename(path)
    return re.findall('\_(\d)[\_]{2}',lst)
```

So eventually I'll get a DataFrame that looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: can u give example. its not clear

Comment: Yes, edited as you asked

Comment: Hope this solves your question. it took me 30 min to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
name_list = ['2021_01_21__11_10_54_1__13928_snapshot.jpg',
       '2021_01_21__12_27_44_1__13934_snapshot.jpg',
       '2021_01_21__11_11_08_2__13928_snapshot.jpg',
       '2021_01_21__12_27_56_2__13934_snapshot.jpg',
       '2021_01_21__11_11_19_3__13928_snapshot.jpg',
       '2021_01_21__12_28_08_3__13934_snapshot.jpg']

import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0]], columns=['count']) # initialize dataframe

for name in name_list:
    count = re.search('\_(\d)[\_]{2}',name).group(1)
    col = re.search('[\_]{2}(\d{5})',name).group(1)
    if ((df['count'] == count)).any():
        df.loc[df['count'] == count, col] = name
    else:
        new_row = pd.DataFrame([[count,name]], columns=['count',col])
        df = df.append(new_row)
df.set_index('count', inplace=True)
print(df)
```

[image: RESULT]

Comment: You can remove the first row after you're done, with `df = df.iloc[1:]`